# como colocar evento touch swipe no Slick Carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Queria saber como adicionar eventos `touch swipe` no meu slideshow [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slideshow').slick({
    autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed:4000,
        speed:800,
    });
});
```

Comment: Mas esse plugin já tem isso nativo...

Comment: @DeeSouza então ele vai pegar automaticamente em smartphones com o sistema de toques ?

Comment: Sim. Aqui funciona. http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda